# Is it possible to extract only the log-likelihood value from logLik object in R?

Tags: r, numbers, extract

Basically I'm trying to find a way to extract the number value of log-likelihood value from logLik object.

E.g., the output:  `'log Lik.' -72.0789 (df=2)` Is it possible to 'extract' only the -72.0789 number so it could be assigned elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `[` to extract the value. e.g.:

```
logLik(mod)[1]
# [1] -10.44608
```

Or `head`:

```
head( logLik(mod) )
# [1] -10.44608
```